# lucence search all? with QueryParser

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

Here's part of my code. Instead of searching the text in desc i'd like to search in everything (desc, title, example, etc). How do i do this? do i make another field call all and copy each field into it? can i do something like "", null or "*" to denote search them all? (I tried each and got no results).

How do i search all fields with my text?

```
public static List<Pair<long, float>> Search(string text)
{
    var searcher = new IndexSearcher(directory, true);
    var parser = new QueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29, "desc", analyzer);
    var query = parser.Parse(text);
    var hits = searcher.Search(query);
    // etc
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be good if lucene implicitly supported the notion of "all". You are left with indexing 1 additional filed (name it as "all") whose contents will be a concatenation of desc, title, example etc but do not store it, just index.

Comment: hmm, what is the difference between yes, no (and i can guess compress). I dont understand why that option exist

Comment: Yes means the data is also stored by lucene and it increases the size of the index. Increase in index size means more time while merging/optimizing operations. But if you want the highlighting functionality then I believe you have to store it. Accept the answer if I've answered your question

Comment: I tried it out and the search works. So storing it helps with highlighting? i never heard of highlighting. So i really dont need to store any of these fields? i'll change it and see what happens. BTW almost all this data is also in my mysql db. I use lucence strictly for searching

Comment: If you have all the data in DB then just index the data without storing anything in lucene except the primary/natural key. This way you perform search against the lucene index and while displaying you can retrieve the details from mysql db. The link between the lucene index and the mysql db is the primary/natural key